# Delete a file with file name that contains only numbers with no file extension using python

Tags: python

I created a script in python, compiled using pyinstaller to store document of any file type in MySql database, giving each file with a specific file number (unique id) with no file extension as file name. The compiled executable file has also no extension. The python script is as follows;

```
        cursor.execute("SELECT DOC_COPY FROM DOC_STORE WHERE DOC_ID=%s", (docID, ))
        docCopy = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        docPath = Path.cwd().joinpath("%s"%docID)
        writeTofile(docCopy, docPath)
        subprocess.run(['open',docPath], check=True)
```

It works perfectly. Whenever a document is selected to view, a copy is saved with the document id as the file name with out any file extension, as per the script. I want to delete all such files (file name containing numbers only) from the folder when the software is closed.

Searched web but did not get an answer

Comment: The fact that the executable and the files have no extension is completely irrelevant. What you actually tried to delete those files, instead, is, and there's absolutely no trace of such attempts in your code. Please provide a proper [mre] of what you tried, or, at least, the results of your research (which, by the way, should be quite a lot for such a simple and actually common need as deleting a file, and the absence of a file extension is normally not an issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not so much clear, However if you requirement is like:

> I want to delete all such files (file name containing numbers only)
> from the folder when the software is closed.

To delete all files with names containing only numbers from the specified folder when the software is closed:

```
import os
import shutil

def cleanup_folder():
    folder_path = Path.cwd()  # Change this to the folder path where the files are stored
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.isdigit():
            file_path = folder_path.joinpath(filename)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)

atexit.register(cleanup_folder)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a 're'(regix) to list and filter files in the directory, and then delete those that match your criteria.

```
    numeric_filename_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+$')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use glob to match specific files you want to delete:

```py
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob("/desired/dir/+([0-9])"):
    # [0-9] is the digit range, and +() indicates 1 or more digits
    os.remove(f)
```

Run this at the end of your program, and it should work